# Convert Wpf Control into pdf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to convert my WPF control into pdf, do anyone helps me with some example?

I have a WPF chart and a listview:
[image]

above image is the output of my WPF, and I want to convert this page into pdf?

anyone can help me with it?below is my code which can create a pdf but inside the pdf have no content, please help.

```
public void SaveCurrentViewToXPS()
        {

            var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

            dialog.AddExtension = true;
            dialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            dialog.Filter = "PDF Document (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == false)
                return;

            FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
            PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
            FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

            PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
            Size pageSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight - 100);
            lw.Width = 2100;
            lw.Height = 2970;

            //Create first page of document
            fixedPage.Children.Add(lw);
            //fixedPage.Children.Add(ColumnChart2);
            ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
            fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

            // write to PDF file
            string tempFilename = "temp.xps";
            File.Delete(tempFilename);
            XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(tempFilename, FileAccess.Write);
            XpsDocumentWriter xWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
            xWriter.Write(fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator);
            xpsDoc.Close();

            PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(tempFilename);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: @SushmaJoshi How about convert a flow document in a Listview to Pdf?

Comment: ` XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(tempFilename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);      
            XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
            DocumentPaginator dp = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowdoc).DocumentPaginator;
            writer.Write(dp);`

Comment: ok thanks for your help @SushmaJoshi

Comment: @SushmaJoshi HI, do you know how to separate into **two Pdf pages**   automatically when the data is too long?Thanks

Comment: if Xps file is spread across 2 pages then pdfSharp will take care of spanning to 2 pages. I guess best way is create your xps document to multiple pages when data overflow, rest conversion will automatically fall in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be the way visuals are added in xps document.

```
    FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
    Size pageSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight - 100);

    var visual = ((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)this.Content).Children[0] as UIElement;
    ((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)this.Content).Children.Remove(visual);
    fixedPage.Children.Add(visual);
    ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);

    fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

    // write to PDF file
    string tempFilename = "temp.xps";
    File.Delete(tempFilename);
    XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(tempFilename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
    xw.Write(fixedDoc);
    xpsd.Close();
    PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(tempFilename, dialog.FileName, 1);
```

refer  https://github.com/EbenZhang/PdfSharp.XPS